# jQuery function is not working on newly added row

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make simple real time calculator without page refresh with jquery.

I added dynamic table row with jquery and applied some method in the input fields but that is not working perfectly in newly added rows.

newly added rows are only working when I change something in the default rows.

Here is my html codes:

```
<button type="button" id="addBillingRow" class="btn btn-success btn-sm fa fa-plus fa-3x float-right">add</button>

<table class="table table-bordered" id="dynamic_field_shipping">
  <thead>
    <tr>        
      <th width="10%">Date</th>
      <th width="20%">Purpose</th>
      <th width="20%">Amount</th>
      <th width="10%">Quantity</th>
      <th width="30%">Total</th>
      <th width="10%">#</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="ship_bill">
      <td>
        12/12/17
      </td>
      <td>
        <input id="purpose" type="text" name="purpose" required>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input id="amount" name="amount" type="text" 
               oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '').replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1');" required>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input id="quantity" name="quantity" required="required" type="number" min="0" value="0">
      </td>
      <td>
        <strong><i><span class="multTotal">0.00</span></i></strong>
      </td>
      <td>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td width="50%"><strong><i>Bill Amount:</i></strong></td>
      <td><strong><i><span id="grandTotal">0.00</span></i></strong></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is my jQuery codes:

```
var i=1;  

$('#addBillingRow').click(function(){  
i++;  
$('#dynamic_field_shipping').append('<tr class="ship_bill" id="row'+i+'"><td></td><td><input id="purpose" type="text" name="purpose" required></td><td><input id="amount" name="amount" type="text" required></td><td><input id="quantity" name="quantity" required="required" type="number" min="0" value="0"></td><td><strong><i><span class="multTotal">0.00</span></i></strong></td><td><a href="" name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn_remove">X</a></td></tr>');  
      }); 

$(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var button_id = $(this).attr("id");
  $('#row'+button_id+'').remove();  
}); 

function multInputs() {
  var mult = 0;
  // for each row:
  $("tr.ship_bill").each(function () {
  // get the values from this row:
  var $amount = $('#amount', this).val();
  var $quantity = $('#quantity', this).val();
  var $total = ($amount * 1) * ($quantity * 1)
  $('.multTotal',this).text($total);
    mult += $total;
  });
  $("#grandTotal").text(mult);
}

$(".ship_bill input").change(multInputs);
```

If you want you can check the live code here:

https://jsfiddle.net/wasid/3xkcLdss/1/

besides I also wanted to use this code in jquery append() for allowing only numbers in input fields. but could not use it either.

```
oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '').replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1');"
```

Comment: just google event delegation

Comment: @PranavCBalan Is correct, this question has been answered multiple times.

Comment: for number input use `type="number"` and `step=1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 $("tbody").on('change', '.ship_bill input', multInputs);
```

Comment: giving lecture is easy but showing example is difficult and you have done the difficult job successfully. Thanks a lot!
I was trying with $(".ship_bill input").on('change', 'tr', multInputs); which didn't work. now I understand it well. Thanks again.